# How to use input "required" attribute in IE?

Tags: html

I used "required" to validate my form but its not work at IE browser. Is this a common error? How to I solve it? Below is my code :

this is my html code which work prefect at Google Chrome and Firefox browser.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1" > 
  Subject : <br/>
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required/> <br/>
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file"id="csv" accept=".csv" required/> <br/>
  Content : <br/>
  <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="10" required></textarea><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="storeQueEmail()"/> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure to specify *which* version of IE is being used. Then see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) - which reports [IE10+ compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=required). For earlier IE versions (or event recent Safari versions) you'll need to find a [JS] shim.

Answer (score 0):

No. `required` attr wont work for less then IE10. So you could use plugins for validata the form

Here the plugin I would recommend for you..

http://ericleads.com/h5validate/

http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/

http://adodson.com/jquery.form.js/